# VCalendar not allowing month selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vcalendar

I have a fully updated vue project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "v-calendar": "^3.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
  },
```

I have (to my knowledge) properly installed V-Calendar, but for some reason, the styles and functionality of the calendar seem to be not working correctly. For example, the date selection option is not available for use. Here is a screenshot

[image]

I have included v-calendar into my main.js file and I have added the CSS to the main js file as well. Based on the docs, I cannot see anything that I could be doing incorrectly.

```
main.js


import "v-calendar/style.css";
```

Comment: Just installation is not enough. You have to import the style and Vcalender dependencies  as well. Can you show the code where you have done this? Or have you done this?

Comment: Yes, I have imported the styles.

Comment: Can you show the file you imported in?

Comment: Updated, thanks!

Comment: You are not importing the vcalender component?

Comment: Also show where you are calling the component.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-sppl6r?file=src%2Fmain.js Here is a working example.